# How do I make dialog windows in java?

Tags: java, swing, dialog, window, joptionpane

I found a webpage on the java site on how to make dialog windows, but it isn't working when I try it. The site said to type:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Window text.");
```

I'm just trying to make a window with a bit of text and an ok button, but when I type this in, my Eclipse IDE wants me to import something for the JOptionPane, and after I do that, it says the the "frame" part is incorrect, that it "cannot be resolved to a variable." What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can you show your whole code plz?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: You really need to avail yourself of the API documentation.  'Coding by copy/paste' when you don't understand the code snippet being copy/pasted, *never* works.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I read the info first, I just copy and paste the code after I've reviewed it. It's easier than just typing it up again. Here's the webpage: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.htm You're right, though, pasting is a bad practice and I should just type every thing manually to get the feel of how coding works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start by making sure you have included the `import javax.swing.JOptionPane;` statement within your import portion of your code.

Next, try using

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Window text.");
```

instead.

For example...

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TestDialog {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Window text.");
    }

}
```

Take a closer look at [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details.

You should also consult the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) when in doubt...

Comment: what is parentComponent here?

Comment: @KickButtowski From the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) - *"parentComponent - determines the Frame in which the dialog is displayed; if null, or if the parentComponent has no Frame, a default Frame is used"* - This allows the dialog to enforce modality on the parent frame/window, so the user must dismiss the dialog before they can interact with frame from which it was launched...

Comment: I know that, but why JFrame cannot be parentComponent here?

Comment: @KickButtowski It can...but I have no context from your "snippet" from which I can derive an answer for your current problem. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Because the OP apparently hasn't constructed any JFrame.

Comment: @DavidConrad While I don't disagree, there is no evidence to support that claim - hence the reason I've not bothered to comment on it ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I didn't ask the question lol I'm just learning

Comment: @KickButtowski Sorry, just reporting back to everybody :P

Answer (score 3):

The first parameter in the call to `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` should be an instance of a `JFrame` or `JWindow` that you want to assign your message dialog to. If you don't have a `JFrame` or `JWindow` but still want to display the message dialog, just put in `null` as the first parameter, like this:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Window text.");
```